# I want to know if there is an Ansible (regex_replace) way cutting off a version number

Tags: bash, shell, ansible

## Is there an Ansible (regex_replace) way cutting off a version number?

I'm working on installing a compressed archive. It is located at **{{ HomeDir }}/ms2install** directory.

Filename: **ms2install_1.16.1.8.tgz**

I have a shell task to get that extracts the version number

```
# Get the version number from the archive
- name: Get MS2 verion number from the the file list
  shell: "ls -1 {{ HomeDir }}/ms2install | grep \"ms2iinstall_.*tgz\" | cut -d_ -f2 | rev | cut -c5- | rev"
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
  register: ms2Num
```

ms2Num is **1.16.1.8**

I am OK with using a shell command here as it does not change the system and the string manipulation in the single command.
No I need to only find **1.16** to find a directory in the remote system after I un-compress the archive.  The directory I want is down a few levels of sub-directories.  I also want to make sure to install packages from the correct directory.

I can extract the **1.16** with a simular shell command.

```
# Get the version number from the archive
- name: Get truncated MS2 verion number from the the file list
  shell: "ls -1 {{ HomeDir }}/ms2install | grep \"ms2i_.*tgz\" | cut -d_ -f2 | rev | cut -c5- | rev | | cut -d. -f1-2"
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
  register: ms2KurtzNum
```

This works and I register a short string **1.16**.

I want to know is there a regex_replace solution to either definitions.  So create a new var with only the first part of the string **1.16**. 
For regex: `/(^(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}))/g` works, but in Ansible the expression does give the "1.16" sub-string.

```
- name: Find version directory
  find:
    paths: "{{ DestDir | join }}/ms2install/patches"
    patterns: "{{ ms2Num.stdout | regex_replace( '([1-9]{1,3}\\.[1-9]{1,3}))' '\\1' ) }}" # <== pattern 1.16
    recurse: yes
    file_type: directory
  register: PatchVersionDir
```

There is enough differences between bash regex and Ansible regex (Python?) to frustrate.

Is there a better solution in Ansible then a shell task?

Comment: Please define `does not work`. $0.01: there seems to be an extra closing parenthesis in your regex. $0.02: there seems to be a missing closing parenthesis to your regex_replace filter. $0.03: you are trying to match something and replace it with exactly what you matched in first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: *"Is there a better solution in Ansible then a shell task?"*

A: Yes. It is. For example the tasks below (given `my_filename: ms2install_1.16.1.8.tgz`)

```
    - set_fact:
        ms2Num: "{{ (my_filename|splitext).0.split('_').1 }}"
    - set_fact:
        ms2Num_short: "{{ ms2Num.split('.')[:2]|join('.') }}"
    - debug:
        msg:
          - "{{ ms2Num }}"
          - "{{ ms2Num_short }}"
```

give

```
    "msg": [
        "1.16.1.8", 
        "1.16"
    ]
```

Comment: This works well.   I figured that there would be some filter 'foo that was needed.  I did not know close to python the syntax would be.

Comment: Pretty much all ansible is python under the hood - I don't actually know anything that isn't - though I'm sure there's examples where it's not.